# Search after current day in MS SQL

Tags: sql-server

i have a table, look like this:
[image]

I want to select just the rows with current date.

```
SELECT Mandant, BelId, Typ, Datum FROM myTable WHERE Datum = DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
```

this is not working i'm getting an empty table

```
SELECT Mandant, BelId, Typ, Datum FROM myTable WHERE Datum = CONVERT(date,GETDATE())
```

this is also not working.

I've tried to convert the Datum column

```
SELECT Mandant, BelId, Typ, CONVERT(date,Datum) AS PPDatum FROM myTable WHERE PPDatum = CONVERT(date,GETDATE())
```

i get an error: 
Invalid column name

What do i make wrong ?

Comment: In your `where` you can't refer to a column alias. What datatype is `Datum`?

Comment: @HoneyBadger Datum is a datetime type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work:

```
SELECT Mandant, BelId, Typ, Datum
FROM myTable
WHERE Datum >= CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
AND Datum <= GETDATE();
```

It will ensure that `Datum` is greater than `'2017-07-10'` and less than current timestamp.

You also can do the following:

```
SELECT Mandant, BelId, Typ, Datum
FROM myTable
WHERE CAST(Datum AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE);
```

But this will result in a execution plan that is not that pretty as above.

Comment: Thank you for solution and explanation. It's working

Answer (score 0):

It should be as simple as

```
SELECT Mandant, BelId, Typ, Datum 
FROM myTable WHERE cast(Datum as date) = cast(GETDATE() as date)
```